Use Existing S3 in a CloudFormation Template to pass as a parameter to a SSM document
I have an S3 already created "ssm-test".
Using cloudFormation template i want to create a SSM document whose task is to copy a certain file from S3 to an Windows Instance in AWS.
i am not sure how to pass the S3 details to the SSM document.

You can construct the document using a !Sub string and reference the bucket using something like ${MyBucket}.
